# node doesn't start when I use exec() to run it

Tags: php, node.js, windows, exec

I am trying to create a website in which I can run a node app with php. it is not supposed to end and is meant to be run forever on the server even if the user leaves the php page. But when I run the code, there is no output and the node.js service (a discord bot) doesn't run.

TestNode is the folder of my node script and it has a index.js inside it with a few other files which aren't important right now. Node.exe is located in the node folder.
The actual command does work because I opened up cmd and tested it from the location of my script(index.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Node</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    
    
     $result = exec("cd TestNode && ..\node\node ..\TestNode\index.js 2>&1");

    echo $result;
    
    

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, that exec() returns only the last line of output of the executed command. It is better to use shell_exec() (at least for debugging) as it returns all of the output of the executed command.

The second thing is, that PHP executed from the browser(through a webserver), uses www-data user and default path the place, where the file is located.

Comment: I did try shell_exec too. It is still blank. And can you please explain what you mean by "uses www-data user and default path the place, where the file is located."

Comment: Anything executed by shell_exec is executed as www-data user and in path where the PHP file is.

Comment: Thanks. But then what do I do? All I found is this script on [github](https://github.com/niutech/node.php/blob/master/node.php) but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: You need to cd to the corresponding folder and probably use another user(for example using su).

Comment: I am on windows. How do I switch user?

Comment: If you're on windows, you need to ensure, that the user, that runs the server(for example apache) has enough permissions to execute in that folder. You can detect the user by running shell_exec("whoami")

Comment: Ok, I will run it as soon as I can. I do know how to elevate a script's rights to admin, but that causes a bunch of security issues.

Comment: It does, but you can only allow executing and writing for a certain user in the folder, so you don't need to run it as Administrator.

Comment: It runs as the user I am logged on to. This is actually a admin account itself

Comment: I am reading your question again, and when I read this: `It is not supposed to end and is meant to be run forever on the server even if the user leaves the PHP page.`. Be aware of PHP timeout, and the thing, that is user leaves the page, it'll end it's loading(And running of the program).

Comment: then what can I do about that?

Comment: Read something about services in windows.